# How to make tables like NSTableView in the iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

Is there a class or framework that lets you draw tables with rows and columns on the iPhone. Or do you have to draw the table yourself and place a textfield in each slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UITableView`. It doesn't have columns because iPhone screen is much smaller than average screen of desktop computer. But if you want you can emulate them with custom `UITableViewCell`s.

Comment: This technique works well. Just tile your own views inside of a UITableViewCell. It isn't that difficult to create a general class to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw the table yourself and place a text field in each slot. It's possible that you could find an open source implementation, but it's not very hard to write one based on a `UIScrollView`, I've done it.